# Обработка данных полученных через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть такой код

```
$('a#div').click( function(event){

тут ajax запрос

тут добавление кода полученного на страницу из ответа ajax запроса

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

в получено ответе есть элементы `a#div`, но `jQuery` их не видит

Comment: А я то думал, что плохо пишу, а нет.

Comment: в каком смысле ? не понятно? или код?

Comment: @MaxGrim не по-русски. да и код покажите, что там у вас не получается, в DOM само по себе ниче не попадает :)

Comment: @eicto так лучше?

Comment: нет не лучше, jsfiddle, вот там пример сделайте. хотя-бы полурабочий вот пример как [там делать $.post()](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QXdAB/) пожалуйста, продемонстрируйте свою проблему.

Comment: а подгружать то откуда?

Comment: ну можно с gist, [вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/CRenU/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wmQTZ/ примерно так

Comment: и где он хотя-бы полурабочий ? **я вам зачем показывал как надо ? выделите проблему, спросите нормально или идите в менеджеры б**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Включаю телепата:**
Чтобы навешивать события на только что созданные элементы, используйте **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Ваш доработанный пример:

```
$('a#div').on('click', function() {
  //тут ajax-запрос
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Обновление:**
*[jsFiddle автора](http://jsfiddle.net/wmQTZ/)*
1) У вас функция *remove_msg()* принимает 4 аргумента, а вы передаете в нее 5.
2) Не понятно, зачем вам она вообще нужна? Вы хотели передать переменные в анонимную функцию? Можно сделать намного проще. (см. мой пример ниже)
3) Вы неправильно навешиваете свой обработчик событий на ссылку...

Вот исправленный и рабочий пример: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wmQTZ/1/)

```
//Эти переменные будут видны внутри анонимной функции, привязанной к ссылке
var a_id = "remove_msg",
    id_re = "data-id",
    where = ".lt_im",
    ajax_file = "removeMsg.php";

$('#message_holder').on('click', 'a#remove_msg', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data_id = $(this).attr(id_re);
    var last_id = $('a#' + a_id + ":last").attr(id_re);

    //Тут ajax-запрос, возвращающий data
    //..

    //Эмулируем действие скрипта после ответа сервера
    //Содержимое data тот же html-код, что и в верстке
    //Меняется только имя пользователя
    //data установлена для демонстрации

    var data = '<div class="lt_im mess" data-id="388"><div class="mess_ots"><div class="lt"><a href="/~test"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></a></div><div class="overfl_hid"><span id="messTime">17:21, 16 Гру</span> <b><a href="/~test">'+randomUser()+'</a></b><span id="tGraySmall"> написал:</span><br/>Текст<br/><span id="like_c"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/noshadow/standart/gif/24x24/001_18.gif"/> <b>1</b></a></span><div id="messSmall"><a id="remove_msg" data-id="388" href="#">Удалить</a></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>';

    //удалили нужный элемент
    $(where + "[" + id_re + "=" + data_id + "]").remove();
    //загрузили новый
    $('#message_holder').append(data);        
});

//Генерирует случайное имя пользователя. Только для наглядности.
function randomUser() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
}
```

**Обновление 2:** **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmQTZ/3/)**

Изменения в верстке.
Было:

```
<div data-info="messMe" data-me="1">
```

Стало:

```
<div id="message_holder" data-info="messMe" data-me="1">
```

В скрипт внесены изменения для лучшей наглядности и добавлен нужный задавшему вопрос функционал. Спасибо **[@eicto](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11304/eicto)** за наводку.

Comment: ага, тоже об этом подумал... тока нельзя делать одинаковые id в одном документе. и это... может ему скорее надо 

    $(document).on('click','a#div',handler) 

?

Comment: @VenZell .on() ничего не дал, именно так я и пробывал

Comment: @eicto а как это можно прикрутить к моему примеру http://jsfiddle.net/wmQTZ/

Comment: @MaxGrim у вас не пример а какашка извиняюсь.

Comment: @eicto а что там не так? там все есть основное кроме того что не добавляет сообщение потому что неоткуда , тем более сайт на денвере

Comment: да все не так, какой к черту денвер ? вы возьмите вашу проблему превратите ее  в работающий код, с помощью fiddle и gist или ещё как, и спрашивайте в конкретном месте, а вы скопипастили кусок говнокода с тупой разметкой и чего-то хотите.

Comment: Снова поработал телепатом и даже собрал вам рабочий пример. Картинки заменил для наглядности.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/28D2U/

Comment: я конечно считал что пишу не идеально но не думал что так плохо что бы вы это называли говнокодом, может и правда он таким и является, тогда прошу вас просветить меня и вывести на путь истинный , научить правильно писать


Пишу тут т.к. нигде не могу больше.

Смысл функции, не копировать один и тот же код для разных параметров.

@VenZell вы конечно изменили код, но суть такова что при удалении сообщения удаляется сообщение и по возможности загружается еще одно из БД

Так вот! Хочу подметить что все работает, не работает только функция на новых, подгруженных сообщениях

Comment: Собрал пример заново. Сначала тоже криво навесил обработчик. Спасибо, @eicto !